# environment host urls convention and using wildcard DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualhost, hostname, dns-zone, physical-environment

we're setting up new hosts and environment servers on our company... creating 3 server instances... dev, stage, production

we've multiple clients and multiple projects per client
so this is our idea:

> **http[s]://[project].[client-code].[environment].[domain].[tld]**
>
> E.g.: http://website.client.stage.example.com

Is this wrong?
Another person on our team said that is better to have the [env] at the top of the url bc that defines the project status...

> **http[s]://[env][project].[client-code].[domain].[tld]**

but we're defining the project server location instead..

> **E.g.: the [project] of [client-code] that is located on the [env] server**

said that..
Our approach allow us to use wildcard DNS for the staging and development servers, so it's easier for us to create the vhost on the server.. and it works instantly (without adding a new record on the DNS table)

> **E.g.: CNAME _____ *.dev _____ dev.domain.tld**

It's a bad idea?
Have in mind that we manage a LOT of clients and projects per client which means at least 2 different DNS entries per project one for dev and one for stage if we decide not to use wildcards.